# FreeNAS zpool import crashing

Tags: zfs, freenas

I had a power interruption that caused more than one issue on my server.  Unfortunately, the backup was running at the time, and needless to say, I am in a bad place with my FreeNAS raid pool.  I have had to replace the USB boot device, but I have been unable to import my storage.  The backup media had the configuration file for FreeNAS and my data.  As such, I just need to try to recover my RAID data if possible.

zpool seems okay when I try the import.

```
[root@freenas ~]# zpool import                                                  
    pool: Asus-i5-FreeNAS                                                        
      id: 10045980464890814809                                                   
   state: ONLINE                                                                 
  status: The pool was last accessed by another system.                          
  action: The pool can be imported using its name or numeric identifier and      
    the '-f' flag.                                                          
     see: http://illumos.org/msg/ZFS-8000-EY                                      
  config:                                                                        

    Asus-i5-FreeNAS                                 ONLINE                  
      raidz2-0                                      ONLINE                  
        gptid/99bce52a-9a2e-11e5-a213-ac220b4f3c4a  ONLINE                  
        gptid/9a7efb22-9a2e-11e5-a213-ac220b4f3c4a  ONLINE                  
        gptid/9b42cc1e-9a2e-11e5-a213-ac220b4f3c4a  ONLINE                  
        gptid/9c07650e-9a2e-11e5-a213-ac220b4f3c4a  ONLINE                  
        gptid/9cd136bd-9a2e-11e5-a213-ac220b4f3c4a  ONLINE                  
        gptid/9d904f64-9a2e-11e5-a213-ac220b4f3c4a  ONLINE
```

I then try the import with a -f Asus-i5-FreeNAS which will crash FreeNAS out to the db> prompt with an error.

```
panic:Solaris(panic) zfs: allocating allocated segment(offset=4399056523264 size=73728) of (offset=4398587316272 size=833703936)

cpuid = 0
KDB: stack backtrace:
db_trace_self_wrapper() at db_trace_self_wrapper+8x2b/frame 0xfffffe8455db73c0
vpanic() at vpanic...
```

See this image for full information: [image: panic trace screen shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was only able to import the pool again using the following command line:
`zpool import -F -m -o readonly=on -f Asus-i5-FreeNAS`

This will import the pool and show that there are 5 permanent errors.